# how to instantiate handler in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, handler

i have used handlers in Android programming when i want to send a value back to a UI thread object like a View.  and i would do that like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

and this is the code for the use inside of a run method:

```
 handler.post(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {

                // access a view on the UI thread

              }
           });
```

however when in a java swing application i want to do the same thing and i get the compiler error "Handler is abstract and cannot be instantiated"  when i try the same thing as shown above.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
```

so if this works in Android, how can i do this same thing in a Java desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

You're on the right track, but in Swing you need to use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) instead ;)